# Query to generate parent name when link could be either parent or child

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my table

```
    table category
    id   catname   childof  isParent
    1    name1       0        yes
    2    name2       1        no
```

etc...

table recipe

```
    id   name      cat
    1    recipe1    1
    2    recipe2    2
```

etc

The only link between the tables is the recipe.cat referencing the category.id. I need a MySQL script to show this:

```
    recipe.name    parent category name
    recipe1             name1
    recipe2             name1
```

So I need it to find use the parent name if it is a parent or a child of a parent. I can create a script to find the parent id:

```
SELECT catname, isparent, id, childof,
case isParent
when 'no' then childof
else id
end as newid
FROM category
```

This gives me the parent ID but not the name.  I need to link the newid alias to the recipe table in order to get the name and this is where I get stuck because I need the join to be either the childof or the ID depending if the cat is a parent or child. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subquery to the rescue:

```
SELECT a.name AS recipe_name, 
CASE b.isParent
    WHEN 'no'
    THEN (SELECT catname FROM category WHERE id = b.childof)
    ELSE b.catname
END AS category_name
FROM recipe AS a, category AS b
WHERE a.cat = b.id
```

Returns:

```
recipe_name | category_name
------------+---------------
recipe1     | name1
recipe2     | name1
```

Answer (score 0):

A second query where you're querying the name of the category using the ID you've obtained maybe?

Comment: I can't use the alias in the join.